# cast using avg as conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to categorize records based on the relation between a value and the average of the value.
This value has been calculated in a previous subquery

I will try and recreate the simplest version of my problem

I'm trying something like this

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    CASE
       WHEN delta > 2 * (AVG(delta) HAVING model = x.model) THEN 'long break'
       WHEN delta < 2 * (AVG(delta) HAVING model = x.model) AND delta > 1.4 * (AVG(delta) HAVING model = x.model) THEN 'short break'   
       WHEN delta < 1.4 * (AVG(delta) HAVING model = x.model) THEN 'no break'
    END AS 'category'
FROM
(
SELECT
     model,
     timestamp,
     timestamp - Lag(timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS time
) [Delta]
FROM T_event) x
```

The t_event table looks like a very simple event logger

```
event_ID     |   Model  |          Timestamp       |
---------------------------------------------------
800              model A     10-09-2019 12:00:00
799              model A     10-09-2019 11:59:46
798              model A     10-09-2019 11:58:59
797              model B     10-09-2019 11:58:22
796              model B     10-09-2019 11:57:51
795              model B     10-09-2019 11:57:42
794              model B     10-09-2019 11:57:32
793              model C     10-09-2019 11:56:21
792              model C     10-09-2019 11:56:05
```

What im trying to get is this

```
Model     |     Timestamp     |     Delta      |   Category 
------------------------------------------------------------
Model A         Timestamp A     TSA - TSA(-1)    based on avg(delta) for each model compared with delta
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think sample data and expected output will be more helpful than this query example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the average operator with time, I changed it to the minute.

```
select 
    x.*,
    case
    when delta > 2 * (AVG(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY Model)) then 'long break'
    when delta < 2 * (AVG(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY Model)) 
     and delta > 1.4 * (AVG(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY Model)) then 'short break'   
    when delta < 1.4 * (AVG(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY Model)) then 'no break'
    end as 'category'
from
(
    select model, timestamp,
        DATEDIFF (MINUTE, Lag(timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID), timestamp) [Delta]
    from T_event
) AS x
```

Comment: The OVER(PARTITION BY Model)) part was exactly what i was after, thank you.
Is there any way to limit the value of the 'deltas' used for the AVG calculation? For example, only deltas with a value of <200 are used for the (AVG(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY Model))

Comment: you can use case in avg function like`AVG(CASE WHEN delta < 200 THEN delta END)`